# Reverse css animation on hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a hamburger menu with 3 spans. I'd like to run my animation on click and reverse it when clicking again. Right now, when you click, the top and bottom span animate and then you click again they should reverse. I tried for hours but couldnt get it so I made 2 separate forward animations and 2 separate reverse animations.

Can anyone show me how I can avoid having all these animations on this?

Please see my pen : [here](https://codepen.io/omarel/pen/PQLvzN)

```js
    $(document).on('click', '#hamburger.unopened', function() {
    $('#hamburger .nav-icon span:nth-of-type(1)').addClass("hamforward__top");
    $('#hamburger .nav-icon span:nth-of-type(3)').addClass("hamforward__btm");
    $('#hamburger').toggleClass('unopened opened');
    $('body').toggleClass('menuopen');
    });
                
    $(document).on('click', '#hamburger.opened', function() {
    $('#hamburger .nav-icon span:nth-of-type(1)').toggleClass("hamforward__top hamreverse__top");
    $('#hamburger .nav-icon span:nth-of-type(3)').toggleClass("hamforward__btm hamreverse__btm");
    $('body').toggleClass('menuopen');
    });
```

```css
     #hamburger {
     width:30px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 40px;
     left: 40px;
     cursor: pointer;
     }
     #hamburger .nav-icon {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     z-index: 30;
     width: 35px;
     visibility: visible;
     opacity: 1;
     height:30px;
     width:100%;
     }
     #hamburger .nav-icon span {
     width: 100%;
     height: 2px;
     width: 100%;
     left: 0;
     background: #fff;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     background-color:black;
     }  
     #hamburger .nav-icon span:nth-of-type(1) {
     top: 0;
     }
     #hamburger .nav-icon span:nth-of-type(2) {
     top: 9px;
     opacity:1;
     }
     #hamburger .nav-icon span:nth-of-type(3) {
     top: 18px;
     }
     .menuopen #hamburger .nav-icon span:nth-of-type(2) {
      opacity:0;
     }
     .menuopen #hamburger .nav-icon span:nth-of-type(2) {
     transition: all 0.4s;
     transition-delay: 0.2s;
     }
     #hamburger .nav-icon span:nth-of-type(2) {
     transition: all 0.4s;
     transition-delay: 0.2s;
     }
     .hamforward__top  {
     -webkit-animation: downuphamburger; 
     -moz-animation: downuphamburger; 
     -o-animation: downuphamburger; 
      animation:downuphamburger;
     }
     .hamreverse__top  {
     -webkit-animation: downuphamburger__reverse; 
     -moz-animation: downuphamburger__reverse; 
     -o-animation: downuphamburger__reverse; 
      animation:downuphamburger__reverse;
     }
        
    .hamforward__btm  {
    -webkit-animation: updownhamburger; 
    -moz-animation: updownhamburger; 
    -o-animation: updownhamburger; 
    animation:updownhamburger;
    }
    .hamreverse__btm  {
    -webkit-animation: updownhamburger__reverse; 
    -moz-animation: updownhamburger__reverse; 
    -o-animation: updownhamburger__reverse; 
    animation:updownhamburger__reverse;
    }
   
   .hamforward__top,
   .hamreverse__top,
   .hamforward__btm,
   .hamreverse__btm  {
   animation-fill-mode: both;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
   }
   .hamforward__top,
   .hamreverse__top,
   .hamforward__btm,
   .hamreverse__btm   {
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   }
   .hamforward__top,
   .hamreverse__top,
   .hamforward__btm,
   .hamreverse__btm {
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.7s; 
   animation-duration:0.7s;
   }
   .x {
   -webkit-animation-delay: .1s; 
   animation-delay:  .1s;
   }

   @keyframes downuphamburger {
   0% {
    top:-5px;
   }
   50% {
    top:11px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
   100% {
   top:11px;
    transform: rotate(132deg);
    }
   }
             
   @keyframes downuphamburger__reverse {
   0% {
   top:11px;
   transform: rotate(132deg);
   }
   50% {
     top:11px;
     transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
   100% {
    top:0px;
    }
   }
 
   @keyframes updownhamburger {
   0% {
     top:23px;
   }
   50% {
     top:11px;
     transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
   100% {
    top:11px;
     transform: rotate(50deg);
     }
   }
   @keyframes updownhamburger__reverse {
   0% {
     top:11px;
     transform: rotate(50deg);
   }
   50% {
     top:11px;
     transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
   100% {
    
     top:18px;
    }
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- start hamburger -->
     <div id="hamburger" class="unopened">
            <div class="nav-icon">
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
      </div>
 <!-- end hamburger -->
```

Comment: Have you looked into [`animation-direction: reverse;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction)?

Comment: I've tried it in so many different ways. It just wont reverse properly the way I made it with all custom animations.